# Link to index in TOC points does not point to index, but to whatever is right before index

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, links

My LaTeX document contains an index which is also referenced in the table of contents via `\addcontentsline`.
The page number displayed in the TOC is correct.
The link, however, is not.
(If I view the document structure in my PDF viewer, Evince, the page number also appears to be wrong.)

I found out that the link always seems to point to whatever is right before the index in the document structure (for example a `section`, `subsection` or `paragraph`).

In my example, the link generated by Pdflatex points to the paragraph "Und so weiter" which is right before the index.
If I remove "Und so weiter" and compile again, the link will point to the subsection "Hallo".

### Minimal working example

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{plain}
\makeindex

\title{Stichwortverzeichnis bei \LaTeX\ korrekt verlinken}
\author{Kunigunde Knitterkleid}

%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\section{Abschnitt 1}
\subsection{Blabla}
Lorem\index{Lorem|see{Lorem ipsum}} ipsum\index{Lorem ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales\index{sodales} commodo, lectus\index{lectus} velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
\clearpage

\section{Abschnitt 2}
\subsection{Hallo}
\paragraph{Und so weiter}
\blindtext
\clearpage

%%%%% INDEX %%%%%

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

**Oddly enough, it works perfectly when using a KOMA script class.**

The only changes I made was changing the document class to `scrartcl` with the option `index=totoc` and removing the unnecessary `\addcontentsline` line.

### Minimal working example using KOMA script

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, index=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{plain}
\makeindex

\title{Stichwortverzeichnis bei \LaTeX\ korrekt verlinken}
\author{Kunigunde Knitterkleid}

%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\section{Abschnitt 1}
\subsection{Blabla}
Lorem\index{Lorem|see{Lorem ipsum}} ipsum\index{Lorem ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales\index{sodales} commodo, lectus\index{lectus} velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
\clearpage

\section{Abschnitt 2}
\subsection{Hallo}
\paragraph{Und so weiter}
\blindtext
\clearpage

%%%%% INDEX %%%%%

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can make the link point to the correct location (apart from using KOMA script instead)?

I am using Tex Live 2009 on Linux.

Comment: I'm still on Ubuntu 10.04 and this is the newest version of Tex Live in the repositories. I know I could get the latest version from tug.org, but I'm going to update my distro soon anyway, so I'll just deal with it at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\addcontentsline` doesn't set an achor; it just refers to the latest previous location where an anchor is set and that's why the hyperlink points to the wrong location (a sectional unit, in your case). To get the correct result, use `\phantomsection` from `hyperref` to set an anchor at the right location:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\printindex
```

Another option is to use the [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package:

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{plain}
\makeindex

\title{Stichwortverzeichnis bei \LaTeX\ korrekt verlinken}
\author{Kunigunde Knitterkleid}

%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\section{Abschnitt 1}
\subsection{Blabla}
Lorem\index{Lorem|see{Lorem ipsum}} ipsum\index{Lorem ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales\index{sodales} commodo, lectus\index{lectus} velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
\clearpage

\section{Abschnitt 2}
\subsection{Hallo}
\paragraph{Und so weiter}
\blindtext
\clearpage

%%%%% INDEX %%%%%

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, using `\phantomsection` worked! Yes, I just read the description for `\phantomsection` in the hyperref documentation and now I know why it's always the last section-like thing the link points to: "\addcontentsline refers to the latest previous location where an anchor is set."